# Xcode 5 storyboard for iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have project that was created in Xcode 4.3, in main View there was thee buttons, i updated xcode and wanted to add some UIButtons, everything works fine in iOS 7 simulator, but some of the buttons that were created in xcode 5 storyboard showing with no Title in iOS 6.1 simulator . Here's example:

[image: iOS 6.1]
[image: iOS 7]

As you can see three buttons (Facts,Eng,Rus) that were created in Xcode 5 storyboard is empty in iOS 6.1 Simulator. How i can make default buttons in storyboard that will be with the same title in iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.0 versions?

Comment: use custom buttons instead, and set your own images for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is really simple, in Xcode 5 storyboard - UIButtons is created with tight borders around it's title, so if you're creating UIButton in Xcode 5 storyboard and have multi-version support in your project, you better stretch created button in storyboard.